# How do I find the number of vertices in a graph created by iGraph in python?

Tags: python, igraph

I'm writing a function that receives a graph as input.
The very first thing I need to do is determine the order of the graph (that is, the number of vertices in the graph).

I mean, I could use `g.summary()` (which returns a string that includes the number of vertices), but then I'd have parse the string to get at the number of vertices -- and that's just nasty.

To get the number of edges I'm using `len(g.get_edgelist())`, which works. But there is no `g.get_vertexlist()`, so I can't use the same method.

Surely there is an easy way to do this that doesn't involve parsing strings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`g.vcount()` is a dedicated function in igraph that returns the number of vertices. Similarly, `g.ecount()` returns the number of edges, and it is way faster than `len(g.get_edgelist())` as it does not have to construct the full edge list in advance.

Answer (score 7):

As some functions in `igraph` have been renamed in meantime, I found the answers here out of date. What the docs suggest now is calling

```
gorder(g)
```

which works for me. Analogy for `ecount` is

```
gsize(g)   # vcount(g) still works, but not g.vcount()
```

It's useful to note that help pages are cleverly redirected, so

```
?vcount
```

brings you to `gorder` docs etc.

Answer (score 2):

`g.vs` should return the sequence of vertices as an `igraph.VertexSeq` object:

```
>>> from igraph import Graph
>>> g = Graph.Formula("A-B")
>>> g.vs["name"]
['A', 'B']
>>> len(g.vs)
2
>>> g.vcount()
2
```

Edit: As @Tamas mentions below, `g.vcount()` will also return the number of vertices. Example edited to account for this.